# jQuery - I need a more efficent way to write my forms

Tags: jquery

```
    //Set default values
 $('#name').val('First Last');
 $('#email').val('you@email.com');
 $('#subject').val('Subject');
 $('#message').val('Message');
    //Change style when user types
 $('#name,#email,#subject,#message').keypress(function() {
  $(this).css({
   'color':'black',
   'font-style':'normal'
   });
 });
    //Check each input for change
 $('#name').focusin(function(){
  if($(this).val() == 'First Last') {
   $(this).val('');
  }
 });
 $('#name').focusout(function() {
  if($(this).val() == '') {
   $(this).val('First Last');
   $(this).css({
    'color':'grey',
    'font-style':'italic'
    });
  }
 });
 $('#email').focusin(function(){
  if($(this).val() == 'you@email.com') {
   $(this).val('');
  }
 });
 $('#email').focusout(function() {
  if($(this).val() == '') {
   $(this).val('you@email.com');
   $(this).css({
    'color':'grey',
    'font-style':'italic'
    });
  }
 });
 $('#subject').focusin(function(){
  if($(this).val() == 'Subject') {
   $(this).val('');
  }
 });
 $('#subject').focusout(function() {
  if($(this).val() == '') {
   $(this).val('Subject');
   $(this).css({
    'color':'grey',
    'font-style':'italic'
    });
  }
 });
 $('#message').focusin(function(){
  if($(this).val() == 'Message') {
   $(this).val('');
  }
 });
 $('#message').focusout(function() {
  if($(this).val() == '') {
   $(this).val('Message');
   $(this).css({
    'color':'grey',
    'font-style':'italic'
    });
  }
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of plugins out there that handle this style of In-Field Labels.

1. [In Field Labels](http://fuelyourcoding.com/scripts/infield/) -- I wrote this one, and it uses positioning to move the label over (or under via z-index) the input area. It has the added benefit of not disappearing completely even after the field has focus. It only hides fully when the user starts to type.
2. [Labelify](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/labelify/) -- Never used it, but it follows your approach of swapping out actual text values.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the "Jquery Form Plugin" available here: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#ajaxSubmit

Good luck!